# Overflow-x space is too wide

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a table on top of another table, both containing `mat-form-field` and `mat-autocomplete` in each row. To make the table responsive, I give the `div` that wraps each table an `overflow-x: auto`. The scrolling works just fine, but the top row of the second table cannot scroll since trying to scroll, it will scroll the upper table instead.

```css
.table wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.one { margin-bottom: 10px; }
.two { margin-top: 10px; }
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper one">
    <table class="table top">
        <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
            <td>{{item.number}}</td>
            <td>
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput noteInput ngModelOptions="{standalone: true}" matAutoComplete="notes" />
                    <mat-autocomplete notes>
                        <mat-option ngFor="let n for notesList">{{n}}</mat-option>
                    </mat-autocomplete>
                </mat-form-field>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

some scrollable content

<div class="table-wrapper two">
    <table class="table top">
        <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
            <td>{{item.number}}</td>
            <td>
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput noteInput ngModelOptions="{standalone: true}" matAutoComplete="notes" />
                    <mat-autocomplete notes>
                        <mat-option ngFor="let n for notesList">{{n}}</mat-option>
                    </mat-autocomplete>
                </mat-form-field>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I tried zeroing the `margin` and increasing it as well, but the 'scrollbar' still overlaps the other content.

[Table one and the scrollable content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9vW7.png)
[Scrollable Content and table two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYgFP.png)
The red rectangle I've marked is the area where the in picture 1 should scroll the content, but it scrolls table one instead, and in picture 2 should scroll table two, but scrolls the content instead. There are no margin or padding as I've checked

Comment: This is a bit unclear, maybe you need to add pictures to explain the problem.

Comment: @André made some edits and added the pictures